# Can I optimize these functions?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have 3 functions (they are minimalized so they might be difficult to read) listed below - i0, t0, and is.

is() and t0() both pull data from the DOM with this line

```
  var c=document.forms[a].elements;
```

would it be better to pull the data from the DOM in i0(), and then pass it to is() and t0()?

That way I would only pull data from the DOM once, but then I would need an extra variable to store it in an pass it to the two functions.

i0():

```
function i0()
  {
  if(t0())
    {
    var a=is('f0');
    s0('bi0.php',a,s2);
    }
  }
```

t0:

```
function t0()
  {
  var a=document.forms['f0'].elements;
  a1="Please enter your credentials";
  a2="That email is not registered";
  a3="Incorrect credentials - Reset your password?";
  if(c0(a,a1,'fb1')&&c2(a[1],a2,'fb1')&&c3(a[2],a3,'fb1'))
    {
    return 1;
    }
  else
    {
    return 0;
    }
  }
```

is():

```
function is(a)
  {
  var b='';
  var c=document.forms[a].elements;
  for(i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
    if(c[i].name)
      {
      if(c[i].type=='checkbox'&&c[i].checked==false)
        {
        b+=c[i].name+"=NULL&";
        }
      else
        {
        b+=c[i].name+"="+c[i].value+"&";
        }
      }
    }
    b=b.slice(0,-1);
  return b;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function i0(a){
    t0() && (a=is('f0'), s0('bi0.php', a, s2)); // just so I can use the comma like this
}

// or

function i0(){
    t0() && s0('bio.php', is('f0'), s2);
}

function t0(){
    var a = document.forms['f0'].elements,
       a1 = "Please enter your credentials",
       a2 = "That email is not registered",
       a3 = "Incorrect credentials - Reset your password?";

    return +( c0(a,a1,'fb1') && c2(a[1],a2,'fb1') && c3(a[2],a3,'fb1') );
}

function is(a){
    var b = '',
        c = document.forms[a].elements;

    for( var i=0, l=c.length; i<l; i++ ){
        c[i].name
            ? c[i].type == 'checkbox' && !c[i].checked && b += c[i].name + '=NULL&'
            : b += c[i].name + '=' + c[i].value + '&';
    }
    return ( b = b.slice(0, -1) );
}
```

---

to answer your actual question, yes doing a single select on `document.forms['f0'].elements` will make things ***slightly*** faster in some browsers, but it's a micro-optimization that I suspect will only be faster in old browsers (IE6) due to the hash-lookup.

Comment: Nah, I'm just making obscure micro-optimizations for the fun of it :)  There's nothing wrong with your code. (well with the exception that you're leaking `a1`, `a2`, `a3` from `t0`)

Comment: I feel like I am looking at alien technology that I can use to make my site better - this is awesome.  Thanks again.

Comment: This saves space + it is more concise + as you mentiond might even be more efficient + it pops you in the eye!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your for loop like this to make it faster, albeit a slight optimization
(Comparison to 0 is faster than comparing to other numbers):

```
for(i = c.length;i > 0;--i)
{
if(c[i].name)
  {
  if(c[i].type=='checkbox'&&c[i].checked==false)
    {
    b+=c[i].name+"=NULL&";
    }
  else
    {
    b+=c[i].name+"="+c[i].value+"&";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI: this is no longer the case in many modern browsers.  Still holds true in general because of prior browsers.

Comment: Oh really? How has that changed?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/compare-num-vs-zero/2  In Chrome and FF all the tests run at the same speed.  In IE comparing to zero is faster. (except, for some reason, Chrome 14.0.814 specifically -- your ___exact___ method is fastest.  Not so in .815)

Comment: very nice.  thanks.  combined this with above for solution.  I'm retitling my question - js masters. IE is 80%+ of browsers.

Comment: It's strange that something like that should act in such a way in different versions of the software, considering on the hardware level, it is quickest to compare to 0.
x_x.

Comment: @Chris Aaker Of course. Too many people use Internet Explorer. It makes developers angry and security specialists worry.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about optimize in time.

*Long way*: Everything can be optimized.
*Short way*: Any optimization in this kind of code will be extremely low

Anyway, function is() is very similar to JQuery *serialize* call and it has been optimizated. Have you considered to use it?

Comment: Can I pull it from the library and have it stand alone in my code?

Comment: It's possible, but it is a very hard job.. (anyway at the end you will have to include a lot of functions)

Comment: Ivan: *"...and it has been optimized."* You wanna [double check that](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.1/src/ajax.js#L215-239)? ;o) @Chris: It wouldn't make sense to load jQuery just for this. Their implementation is integrated and designed to work seamlessly into jQuery's overall structure, and performance will most certainly be greatly reduced.