# What/Why is this code leaking?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I was told that this code is leaking a1,a2,a3 in this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603989/can-i-optimize-these-functions)

```
function t1()
  {
  var a=document.forms['f1'].elements;
  a1="Please fill out all fields";
  a2="Please enter your name using only letters and dashes";
  a3="Please enter a valid email address";
  a4="Password must be atleast 6 characters";
  if(c0(a,a1,'fb2')&&c1(a,a2,'fb2')&&c2(a[2],a3,'fb2')&&c3(a[3],a4,'fb2'))
    {
    return 1;
    }
  else
    {
    return 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in the previous post, "leaking" referred to the fact that the variables `a1` through `a4` are not declared correctly in the scope of the function `t1()`.  Without a `var` keyword, they become global variables.

```
var a1="Please fill out all fields";
var a2="Please enter your name using only letters and dashes";
var a3="Please enter a valid email address";
var a4="Password must be atleast 6 characters";
```

You might have intended to end each of those lines with a comma `,` instead of a semicolon `;`, which would chain them all  into a single statement sharing the first `var` keyword.  In that case, they would not have become global. Just be sure to terminate the last one with `;`.  However, I think it is more readable and better practice to keep each as its own statement as I've done above.

There are lots of blog posts out there about JS variable leaks. [Here's one I just found to get you started...](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-global-variable-leaks/)

Comment: but, if those are treated globaly, they are like singletons, i.e. there are only those 4 and that's it...Unless this function is called many many times from many many different scopes.

Comment: @Italy Moav static vars would be a better term than singletons.  But we don't know the context in which they're called.

Comment: Leak - because there is no var keyword they are global variables.  Just did not know the "jargon".  I was optimizing something else and had not cleaned these up.  One way to create local static variables is to create them like this "function_name"."variable_name".  These are global meaning they have global scope and in a sense could be considered static because once they are set the persist until you do something with them.

Comment: @Chris Aaker I think you've got it. Cheers.